# logstash crashes on solaris

Tags: java, logstash

Logstash crashes on Solaris. Following is the command used to invoke logstash:

/opt/softwares/jdk1.7.0_01/jre/bin/java -d64 -jar logstash-1.2.1-flatjar.jar agent -f logstash.conf

```
Crash log:
#                                                                                               
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGBUS (0xa) at pc=0xffffffff5924ae44, pid=21397, tid=328
#
# JRE version: 7.0_01-b08
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (21.1-b02 mixed mode solaris-sparc compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0xa4ae44]  Unsafe_GetLong+0x154
#
```

Also installed the sparcv9 JDK patch as mentioned in https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-665 but did not work.

isainfo -v output:

```
64-bit sparcv9 applications
        asi_blk_init vis2 vis popc 
32-bit sparc applications
        asi_blk_init vis2 vis popc v8plus div32 mul32
```